# Use of cbegin and cend in vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase, const-iterator

I want to observe the difference between cbegin and begin.

But when i use cbegin i am getting the same result as begin.
According to definition cbegin will return const itertaor and we cant modify the element using the const iterator returned by cbegin.
But, still i am able to erase the element at particular position.

```
    for (auto i = g1.cbegin(); i != g1.cend(); ++i){             
            cout << *i << " ";
    }
    //below code erases element at const pointer
    g1.erase(i);
```

Comment: As I understand it it means only you cannot change the value of the item the iterator points to but you still can modify the container (aka erasing)

Answer (score 6):

The member function erase accepts const_iterator(s).

For example

```
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
```

In early Standards the function indeed was declared with non-constant iterators.

Take into account that the function returns a non-constant iterator but it can be converted implicitly to a constant iterator and can be compared with constant iterators.

By the way this call

```
g1.erase(i);
```

erases nothing because after the loop `i` is equal to the iterator returned by the function `cend` provided that the name i is defined before the loop.

```
auto i = g1.cbegin();
for (; i != g1.cend(); ++i){             
        cout << *i << " ";
}
//below code erases element at const pointer
g1.erase(i);
```

You can erase an element of the vector using the const_iterator because the vector itself is not constant. If the vector would be constant you could not erase its element.

That is the `erase` member function changes the vector itself (so it may not be applied to a constant vector), but it does not change elements of the vector using the const_iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Vlad from Moscow.

I just tried *i=3; in the loop where i am using cend and cbegin.

for (auto it = g1.cbegin(); it != g1.cend(); ++it){

```
            cout << *it << " ";

           *it=3;       

    }
```

I got compilation error :
error: assignment of read-only location ‘it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >::operator*()’
           *it=3;
               ^